# Перехват записи в файл

Tags: windows, sdk

Есть ли в Windows возможность получить поток записываемого файла, т.е. например данные пишутся в log, можно ли получать эти данные в другой программе напрямую, т.е. минуя чтение файла? сейчас использую FSEvents, но хотелось бы найти другой способ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрите в сторону [EasyHook](https://easyhook.github.io/)

Вот статья про него: [EasyHook - The reinvention of Windows API hooking](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27637/EasyHook-The-reinvention-of-Windows-API-hooking)

Можете ещё в эту сторону глянуть, но тут хардкор: [Installable file systems driver design guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/index)

Вот ещё интересная статья, но за SDK тут денег просят. [Monitor and Control Windows File Access in Real-Time](https://www.easefilter.com/Forums_Files/Monitor_Control_File_Access.htm)